how can i use RNFirebase with expo-go
I have been attempting to use the modular firebase sdk with RN for quite some days now... just learned about react-native-firebase upon reading the docs, I found how to use it with regular bare react-native not with expo-go react native
I Have a Problem writing native code, any solutions using it please also give the code\
I have tried using firebase sdk for auth and database, auth works fine, but database cant write...
where I write (to database)...
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { useUid } from '../Backend/UidContext';
import {Button, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';
import { getDatabase, ref, child, push, update } from "firebase/database";
import style from "../Style";

const Post = ({user}) => {
    const [post, setPost] = useState('');
    const [newPostAdded, setNewPostAdded] = useState(false);

    const Tuid = useUid();// Move the useUid hook call inside the component

    const uid = Tuid["uid"]

    function HandlePost(){
        const db = getDatabase();

        // A post-entry.
        const postData = {
            text: post,
        };

        // Get a key for a new Post.
        const newPostKey = push(child(ref(db), 'posts')).key;

        // Ensure the uid is a valid string before using it in the Firebase database reference
        if (typeof uid === 'string' && uid.length > 0) {
            // Remove invalid characters from the uid using a regular expression
            const sanitizedUid = uid.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');

            // Write the new post's data simultaneously in the posts list and the user's post list.
            const updates = {};
            updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
            updates['/user-posts/' + sanitizedUid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

            update(ref(db), updates)
                .then(() => {
                    setPost('');
                    setNewPostAdded(true);
                });
            console.log('Updated')
        } else {
            console.error('Invalid uid:', uid);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (newPostAdded) {
            setNewPostAdded(false);
            // Perform any additional actions or update state variables to reset the component
        }
    }, [newPostAdded]);

    return (
        <View style={style.container}>
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Enter new post"
                    value={post}
                    onChangeText={setPost}
                />
                <Button title="Add Post" onPress={HandlePost}/>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Post;


code for UID
const userCredential= await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
            console.log('User registered successfully!');
            isNotLoggedIn  = false;

            const firebaseUid = userCredential.user.uid;
            // You might want to setUid(firebaseUid) here as well if needed

            setUid(firebaseUid)

            // Example database operation
            const db = getDatabase();
            const postData = { user: firebaseUid };
            const updates = {};
            updates['/user-posts/' + firebaseUid + '/'] = postData;
            await update(ref(db),updates);

thanks for your help
